# Setting up a simple QoS priority flag for VoIP traffic on a Cisco ASA 5505 device through ASDM

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am trying to set up a simplistic QoS policy on our ASA 5505 device. I cannot get the thing to work for the life of me. Basically we want to make sure that all outbound VoIP traffic is prioritized above all other traffic. FYI our PBX box is outside of the LAN.

I am also trying to do this entirely in ASDM. So far I have mostly been able to avoid CLI. However I am open to suggestions in CLI.

I've gone into  Config -> Firewall -> Service Policy Rules and configured the same policy (on both inside interface and outside interface, although I believe it is the inside one that matters here). The policy is:

MATCH Source: inside-network/24 Destination: any Service: voip-group Rule action: QoS enable priority for this flow.

I have configured the source service as voip-group as well (I want it to know that packets using services in voip-group sent from inside-network should be prioritized).

It is not working.

Please help! I can provide more info if you tell me what to provide.

EDIT 0: I have gone into the Packet Tracer and watched the slick little animation to no avail. It does not have a QOS step leading me to think that the rule is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin -- simple is not a word that should be used to describe Quality of Service.  The entire word itself is a loaded term.

Instead of rehashing a lot of details about ASA QoS here, [reference this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/322621/qos-on-cisco-asa-5505-by-vlan-subnet/322803#322803).

Below is the ***ASA 8.4 CLI*** necessary to create a priority queue and handle a specific volume of calls based on a certain bitrate.

- Understand that policing only happens in the out direction on the ASA interface on which it is configured.
- Based on G.711 voice codec @ 87.5 kilobits per second Ethernet layer 2 data rate (includes all overheads)
- Based on a 218 byte average complete Ethernet frame size per voice payload interval. For more [see this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk652/tk698/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094ae2.shtml).
- Based on a need to handle 10 calls at a time (87.5 Kilobits per second * 10 = 875 Kilobits per second).  Note that this is only in the out direction.  We can't "prioritize" incoming traffic unless you control that path as well.
- Based on a maximum delay of 200 milliseconds between the VoIP endpoints.
- Using an extended access-list with source and destination IP for matching VoIP traffic.  Another option is to use IP DSCP if the phones are marking.  By using a simple ACL we can verify the service-policy later on with `show service-policy flow`.

Numbers used for `queue-limit` and `tx-ring-limit` determined using the worksheet in the configuration guide and then massaged.  ***The numbers used here could be drastically different depending on your requirements.***

```
access-list voip-traffic remark [[ match inside to Call Manager ]]
access-list voip-traffic extended permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 1.2.3.4

priority-queue outside
queue-limit 100  ! based on factors listed earlier, very important number
tx-ring-limit 5  ! based on factors listed earlier

! create class-map

class-map voip-class
 match access-list voip-traffic

! create policy-map, advise not using a global policy

policy-map outside-policy
 class voip-class
  priority

! assign policy to interface, in this case outside

service-policy outside-policy interface outside
```

- In this case the `outside-policy` can be assigned to the `outside` interface and you can still implement a `global-policy` that is by its nature assigned to the `outside` interface as well -- *as long as there are not QoS actions on any of the class's listed in the `global-policy`*.  The QoS actions of the `outside-policy` will be in effect and the non-QoS actions (inspects, etc.) of the `global-policy` will stay effect.

You can view priority-queue statistics with `show priority-queue statistics outside`.

You can verify that the traffic itself will hit the priority queue with a command like `show service-policy flow host 10.0.0.100 host 1.2.3.4` which will show you how the existing service policies on all interfaces would react to the traffic specified.

Comment: I ended up figuring most of this out myself a while ago and should have answered my own question, but thank you for a detailed answer.

Comment: Now if only FTD could match on QoS markings with an extended access list so Security Policies could do things with QoS markings.... since FTD doesn't support priority queueing yet.