# Cisco ASA Shaping

Tags: cisco-asa

I am trying to traffic shape on my 5505. I can do the usual policing but as always with policing, it goes up and down and doesn't result in the best results.

I get the message about `ERROR: 'shape' can only be configured for class "class-default"`
, when trying to create my own class-map, though I can't figure out a way to tie the class-default map down by port.

Here's what I get when trying my own class and policy:

```
ASA(config)# class-map test
ASA(config-cmap)# match port tcp eq 80
ASA(config-cmap)# exit
ASA(config)# policy-map test
ASA(config-pmap)# ?

MPF policy-map configuration commands
  class        Policy criteria
  description  Specify policy-map description
  exit         Exit from MPF policy-map configuration mode
  help         Help for MPF policy-map configuration commands
  no           Negate or set default values of a command
  rename       Rename this policy-map
  <cr>
ASA(config-pmap)# class test
ASA(config-pmap-c)# ?

MPF policy-map class configuration commands:
  exit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  help             Help for MPF policy-map class/match submode commands
  no               Negate or set default values of a command
  police           Rate limit traffic for this class
  priority         Strict scheduling priority for this class
  quit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  service-policy   Configure QoS Service Policy
  set              Set connection values
  shape            Traffic Shaping
  user-statistics  configure user statistics for identity firewall
  <cr>
  csc              Content Security and Control service module
  flow-export      Configure filters for NetFlow events
  inspect          Protocol inspection services
  ips              Intrusion prevention services
ASA(config-pmap-c)# shape ?

mpf-policy-map-class mode commands/options:
  average  configure token bucket: CIR (bps) [Bc (bits)], send out Bc only per
           interval
ASA(config-pmap-c)# shape av
ASA(config-pmap-c)# shape average ?

mpf-policy-map-class mode commands/options:
  <64000-154400000>  Target Bit Rate (bits per second), the value needs to be
                     multiple of 8000
ASA(config-pmap-c)# shape average 64000
ERROR: 'shape' can only be configured for class "class-default"
ASA(config-pmap-c)#
```

Now, going off the class-default class, here's what I can do:

```
ASA(config)# policy-map tester
ASA(config-pmap)# ?

MPF policy-map configuration commands
  class        Policy criteria
  description  Specify policy-map description
  exit         Exit from MPF policy-map configuration mode
  help         Help for MPF policy-map configuration commands
  no           Negate or set default values of a command
  rename       Rename this policy-map
  <cr>
ASA(config-pmap)# class class-default
ASA(config-pmap-c)# ?

MPF policy-map class configuration commands:
  exit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  help             Help for MPF policy-map class/match submode commands
  no               Negate or set default values of a command
  police           Rate limit traffic for this class
  priority         Strict scheduling priority for this class
  quit             Exit from MPF class action configuration mode
  service-policy   Configure QoS Service Policy
  set              Set connection values
  shape            Traffic Shaping
  user-statistics  configure user statistics for identity firewall
  <cr>
  csc              Content Security and Control service module
  flow-export      Configure filters for NetFlow events
  inspect          Protocol inspection services
  ips              Intrusion prevention services
```

As you can see, I have no options to limit by port, etc.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

For completeness, here's sh ver:

```
ASA(config-pmap-c)# sh ver

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 8.4(2)
Device Manager Version 6.4(5)206

Compiled on Wed 15-Jun-11 18:17 by builders
System image file is "disk0:/asa842-k8.bin"
Config file at boot was "startup-config"

ASA up 2 hours 7 mins

Hardware:   ASA5505, 512 MB RAM, CPU Geode 500 MHz
Internal ATA Compact Flash, 128MB
BIOS Flash M50FW016 @ 0xfff00000, 2048KB

Encryption hardware device : Cisco ASA-5505 on-board accelerator (revision 0x0)
                             Boot microcode        : CN1000-MC-BOOT-2.00
                             SSL/IKE microcode     : CNLite-MC-SSLm-PLUS-2.03
                             IPSec microcode       : CNlite-MC-IPSECm-MAIN-2.06
                             Number of accelerators: 1

 0: Int: Internal-Data0/0    : address is e05f.b9ab.be21, irq 11
 1: Ext: Ethernet0/0         : address is e05f.b9ab.be19, irq 255
 2: Ext: Ethernet0/1         : address is e05f.b9ab.be1a, irq 255
 3: Ext: Ethernet0/2         : address is e05f.b9ab.be1b, irq 255
 4: Ext: Ethernet0/3         : address is e05f.b9ab.be1c, irq 255
<--- More --->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that as of the current release (ASA 8.4.2) it is not possible to perform traditional QoS `shape` on specific traffic.  The ASA can only `shape` **all** traffic on a given interface to a specified rate.

Use the following [relevant section in the ASA QoS Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/conns_qos.html#wp1065249) as a complete reference.  You may find [this interesting as well](https://serverfault.com/questions/322621/qos-on-cisco-asa-5505-by-vlan-subnet/322803#322803).